# SQL Stored Procedure Fix

Tags: sql-server

Basically my stored procedure below will check the users when they login to the game if they have enough points at specific level and if they have less than what we require for that level, the procedure will fix their points and add them the required @NewPoint to make them @Total = to how much they should have at that level. The script below works correctly, so If they have less @Total points it will update their heros correctly but if they have normal points = and not less < then the script will try to insert NULL to the database and it will fail. So, basically I need help with setting something in this script, so if they have @Total points and not less then what it is specified to abort the script or make something like it will do nothing.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[REPAIR_USER_STAT_POINTS]

@strUserID varchar(21)

AS

DECLARE @Level int, @Point int, @Class int,@NewPoint int, @Strong int, @Sta int, @Dex int, @Intel int, @Cha int, @Total int



SELECT @Level = Level, @Class = Class, @Point = Points, @Strong = Strong, @Sta = Sta, @Dex = Dex, @Intel = Intel, @Cha = Cha FROM USERDATA WHERE strUserId = @strUserID

SET @Total = SUM(@Strong + @Sta + @Dex + @Intel + @Cha + @Point)


IF @Level = 61 AND @Total < 482

BEGIN

SET @NewPoint = 10

END

IF @Level = 62 AND @Total < 487

BEGIN

SET @NewPoint = 15

END

IF @Level = 63 AND @Total < 492

BEGIN

SET @NewPoint = 20

END

IF @Level = 64 AND @Total < 497

BEGIN

SET @NewPoint = 25

END

IF @Level = 65 AND @Total < 502

BEGIN

SET @NewPoint = 30

END

IF @Level = 66 AND @Total < 507

BEGIN

SET @NewPoint = 35

END

IF @Level = 67 AND @Total < 512

BEGIN

SET @NewPoint = 40

END

IF @Level = 68 AND @Total < 517

BEGIN

SET @NewPoint = 45

END

IF @Level = 69 AND @Total < 522

BEGIN

SET @NewPoint = 50

END

IF @Level = 70 AND @Total < 527

BEGIN

SET @NewPoint = 55

END

IF @Level = 71 AND @Total < 532

BEGIN

SET @NewPoint = 60

END

IF @Level = 72 AND @Total < 537

BEGIN

SET @NewPoint = 65

END

IF @Level = 73 AND @Total < 542

BEGIN

SET @NewPoint = 70

END

IF @Level = 74 AND @Total < 547

BEGIN

SET @NewPoint = 75

END

IF @Level = 75 AND @Total < 552

BEGIN

SET @NewPoint = 80

END

IF @Level = 76 AND @Total < 557

BEGIN

SET @NewPoint = 85

END

IF @Level = 77 AND @Total < 562

BEGIN

SET @NewPoint = 90

END

IF @Level = 78 AND @Total < 567

BEGIN

SET @NewPoint = 95

END

IF @Level = 79 AND @Total < 572

BEGIN

SET @NewPoint = 100

END

IF @Level = 80 AND @Total < 577

BEGIN

SET @NewPoint = 105

END

IF @Level = 81 AND @Total < 582

BEGIN

SET @NewPoint = 110

END

IF @Level = 82 AND @Total < 587

BEGIN

SET @NewPoint = 115

END

IF @Level = 83 AND @Total < 592

BEGIN

SET @NewPoint = 120

END
ELSE @NewPoint = @NewPoint

IF @Class = 201 OR @Class = 205 OR @Class = 206 OR @Class = 101 OR @Class = 105 OR @Class = 106

BEGIN

UPDATE USERDATA Set Strong = '247',Dex = '60',Sta = '65',Intel = '50',Cha = '50',Points = @NewPoint WHERE strUserId = @strUserId

END

ELSE IF @Class = 202 OR @Class = 207 OR @Class = 208 OR @Class = 102 OR @Class = 107 OR @Class = 108

BEGIN

UPDATE USERDATA Set Strong = '60',Dex = '252',Sta = '60',Intel = '50',Cha = '50',Points = @NewPoint WHERE strUserId = @strUserId

END

ELSE IF @Class = 203 OR @Class = 209 OR @Class = 210 OR @Class = 103 OR @Class = 109 OR @Class = 110

BEGIN

UPDATE USERDATA Set Strong = '50',Dex = '70',Sta = '50',Intel = '70',Cha = '232',Points = @NewPoint WHERE strUserId = @strUserId

END

ELSE IF @Class = 204 OR @Class = 211 OR @Class = 212 OR @Class = 104 OR @Class = 111 OR @Class = 112

BEGIN

UPDATE USERDATA Set Strong = '65',Dex = '60',Sta = '65',Intel = '232',Cha = '50',Points = @NewPoint WHERE strUserId = @strUserId

END
```